# Is it possible to use a for loop in <select> in html? and how?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a for loop in html  but i dont even know if this is possible. Is it? and if yes how? I dont want to use php. only html and javascript.

this is my goal: i have a file containing .txt files. i want to count the number of txt files and when i get the number i want to send it to  where i will use a for loop to put the txt file's numbers in a dropbox.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a for loop in javascript and add options element in your <select> element in that loop. That will server your purpose.

Comment: in html - no. in javascript - yes. What is it that you want to achieve.

Comment: ok this is my goal: i have a file containing .txt files. i want to count the number of txt files and when i get the number i want to send it to <select> where i will use a for loop to put the txt file's numbers in a dropbox.

Comment: @user1438482 - you can't read the filesystem from javascript. You would need a server side language for that, like php, asp.net. Get that data throught ajax and then run a loop in javascript over that data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lots of answers.... here is another approach **NOT** using document.write OR innerHTML OR jQuery....

HTML

```
<select id="foo"></select>
```

JS

```
(function() { // don't leak
    var elm = document.getElementById('foo'), // get the select
        df = document.createDocumentFragment(); // create a document fragment to hold the options while we create them
    for (var i = 1; i <= 42; i++) { // loop, i like 42.
        var option = document.createElement('option'); // create the option element
        option.value = i; // set the value property
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("option #" + i)); // set the textContent in a safe way.
        df.appendChild(option); // append the option to the document fragment
    }
    elm.appendChild(df); // append the document fragment to the DOM. this is the better way rather than setting innerHTML a bunch of times (or even once with a long string)
}());
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/5J29g/) to demo it.

Comment: My answer is only here because all of the other answers are horrible examples of how to loop the options generation in js. I do however strongly suggest you do this on the server... if you want this to be dynamic and are using XHR to grab some JSON list of files then this might be useful for you. (if you are not I have left you some *hint* terms to google for)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can  for example
write this code in html body tag

```
<select>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

for(var d=1;d<=31;d++)
{
    document.write("<option>"+d+"</option>");
}
</script>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can play with javascript and innerHTML. Try this

HTML

```
<body onload="selectFunction()">
<select id="selectId">

</select>
```

Javascript

```
function selectFunction(){  
    var x=0;   
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
    var option = "<option value='" + x + "'>Label " + x + "</option>"
    document.getElementById('selectId').innerHTML += option;   
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<select id="day" name="day"></select>    
<script type='text/javascript'>
for(var d=1;d<=31;d++)
{
var option = "<option value='" + d + "'>" + d + "</option>"
document.getElementById('day').innerHTML += option;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

No you can't use a for loop in HTML. HTML is a markup language, you cannot use logical code. However you could use [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) to do your logic depending on what your objective is.

Here is an example using jQuery, a popular javascript library:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    $("select").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/T4UXw/

Comment: @mdk Can you please provide an example of this. I've never seen a for loop in HTML, and I don't understand how this would be possible

Comment: @mdk That's javascript, not HTML

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use DynamicHTML. Let the html page have a place holder for the `options` of `select` tag.

```
<select id="selectBox"></select>
```

In a js file

```
var options = ["one","two","three"], selectHtml = "";

for(var optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < options.length; optionIndex++) {

    selectHtml += ("<option>" + options[optionIndex] + "</option>");

}

document.getElementById("selectBox").innerHTML = selectHtml;
```

Put the above code in a function and call that function onload.

Answer (score -2):

HTML is not a programming language, just a markup language, so it doesn't include things like for loops or if statements. Javascript does though. You could use javascript to generate/manipulate the HTML, and thus use for loops to create your <option> tags inside the <select>. As a startup for javascript see checkout w3schools.com

I don't like using plain javascript though, I would rather choose a javascript framework like jQuery to do this. Using jquery it is really easy to do cross-platform compatible manipulation of the HTML dom using javascript. You would only need to include some extra javascript files inside your HTML to get it working.
See http://jquery.com/

An example of using jquery would be this:

```
<select id='myselect'></select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var values=[[1,'tree'],[2,'flower'],[3,'car']];
for(v in values){
    var option=$('<option></option>');
    option.attr('value',values[v][0]);
    option.text(values[v][1]);
    $('#myselect').append(option);
}
</script>
```

You can also try this out on http://jsfiddle.net/6HUHG/3/